# Review page mangled (When question has embedded photo?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, quality-evaluation

Unfortunately I can't make this happen again because the post is gone from the review page since I've already reviewed it. And I didn't fetch a screen grab because I was trying to see if it would happen twice...

This question: [What is this pink flower with dark green leaves?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/what-is-this-pink-flower-with-dark-green-leaves) was on the review page.

I was looking at https://gardening.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=week (review -> first questions -> week).

The question above was listed, I clicked review question, and instead of seeing the question expand, I saw the photo spill under the right-hand nav/stats column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using Firefox, as that's the only browser I could reproduce this issue with. Yet another instantiation of a little [Firefox peculiarity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78384/user-history-screen-has-a-ui-bug-in-firefox-gecko-browsers/78509#78509) with regard to floats. Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that important detail: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111107 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.24`. Thanks.

Comment: @bstpierre Firefox 3.x? I hear they're up to 20 something now... o_O. Seriously speaking, SE only supports the current and the previous version (with things possibly working fine in the ones before that), so that means FF 7 & 8. You can see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) for more info :)

Comment: @yoda: Note the "Ubuntu 10.04" in there too, that means I'm not on the bleeding edge... someday I'll upgrade